# Github Desktop not deleting unstaged files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I currently have a remote repository that is 9 commits in front of my local repository.

The problem is my remote repository has the files I need & my local repository holds files I do not want or need.

With this in mind I don't want to `stash` the files.

I have tried the below varients;

```
git clean
git clean -f
git checkout -- someBladeTemplate.blade.php
git checkout -- .
```

If I run `git status` I get 14 modified but unstaged files. Then, if I run `git clean -n` to list files that would be removed, I get nothing.

Apologies, I'm new to git! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between 'modified but unstaged' files, and 'files not under version control'.

`git clean` removes files that are not under version control, which means they are files that are not staged and are not previously committed.

The modified files *are* under version control, and are not affected by `git clean`.

If you simply want to abort any changes you made to version controlled (or 'tracked') files, you could do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This has the same effect as:

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I would suggest to use `git stash` rather than `git reset --hard` because the latter is irreversible: use with extreme caution!